# RoR - How to query user inputs in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I am creatig a RoR application where I have admin users who can edit a products list and a price list, and I have regular users who can create, edit and view quotes.

My models look like these:

```html
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :quotes
end
```

```html
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :prices
    has_many :relationships
    has_many :quotes, through: :relationships
    validates :name, presence: true
    validates :description, presence: true
end
```

```html
class Price < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
end
```

```html
class Relationship < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :quote
    validates :product_id, presence: true
end
```

EDIT - Quotes Model:

```html
class Quote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  has_many :relationships
  has_many :products, through: :relationships
  has_many :prices, through: :products
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :t_name, presence: true
  validates :b_name, presence: true
  validates :maturity, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true }
end
```

My quotes controller look like this:

```html
class QuotesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user
  before_filter :authorize_admin, only: [:index]
  
  def index
    @quotes = Quote.all
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def show
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @products = Product.all
  end

  def new
    @quote = Quote.new
    @products = Product.all
  end
  
  def create
    @quote = Quote.new(quote_params)
    @products = Product.all
    if @quote.save
      flash[:success] = "Cotización creada correctamente!"
      redirect_to @quote
    else
      @products = Product.all
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  
  def edit
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @products = Product.all
  end
  
  def update
    @quote = Quote.find(params[:id])
    @products = Product.all
    if @quote.update_attributes(quote_params)
      flash[:success] = "Cotización actualizada!"
      redirect_to @quote
    else
      @products = Product.all
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
  
  def destroy
    Quote.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Cotización eliminada"
    redirect_to quotes_url
  end

  private

    def quote_params
      params.require(:quote).permit(:t_name, :b_name, :maturity, product_ids:[])
    end
end
```

As of now, the user is able to create and edit a new quote with this form:

```html
<% provide(:title, 'Nueva cotización') %>
<h1>Nueva cotización</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(@quote, url: new_quote_path) do |f| %>
      <%= render 'shared/error_messages_quotes' %>

      <%= f.label :t_name, "Nombre del tomador" %>
      <%= f.text_field :t_name, class: 'form-control' %>
      
      <%= f.label :b_name, "Nombre del beneficiario" %>
      <%= f.text_field :b_name, class: 'form-control' %>
      
      <%= f.label :maturity, "Año de maduración" %>
      <%= f.text_field :maturity, class: 'form-control' %>
      
      <%= hidden_field_tag "quote[product_ids][]", nil %>
      <% Product.all.each do |product| %>
        <%= check_box_tag "quote[product_ids][]", product.id, @quote.product_ids.include?(product.id) %>
        <%= product.name %>
      <% end %>
      
      <%= f.submit "Crear cotización", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

The quotation information saves and in the show.html I am able to view the information that the user inputed in the quote. However, I have not been able to find out how I can search the prices table for the product_ids selected and the maturity year given...

Any ideas?

BitBucket Link: https://bitbucket.org/aleanzola/cotizador/src

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Comment: Doesn't this work: `Product.joins(:prices).where(id: product_ids)`. Where product_ids is an array of ids you want to query for

Comment: could you add the Quote model to the question?

Comment: We can't see your c9 files... Push to github

Comment: @oreoluwa Thanks! But I also need to lookup that it matches matches the maturity year the user inputed...

Comment: @neydroid Just edited it with the Quote model

Comment: @Timmy Von Heiss Sorry, just edited with the correct Bitbucket link, can you see the files now?